# toggle tabs with vue props not working - Quasar

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, quasar-framework, quasar

I have quasar tabs that are being rendered in v-for loop.
Problem is that when I provide array as prop from parent, then my tabs stop working to toggle whereas it works with local array.

```
<div v-for="test in tests">
  <q-tabs
    v-model="test.status"
    align="justify"
      >
        <q-tab
          v-for="(tab, tabIndex) in tabs"
          :key="tabIndex"
          :name="tab.value"
        >
          {{ tab.name }}
        </q-tab>
      </q-tabs>
</div>
<script>
export default {
props: ['tests']
data (){
return {
  tabs: [
          {
            name: 'Required',
            value: 'required'
          },
          {
            name: 'Not Required',
            value: 'not-required'
          }
        ]
 }
}
```

Tests Data

```
[
  {
    id: "test 1"
    name: 'TEST 1'
    status: 'required'
  },
  {
    id: "test 2"
    name: 'TEST 2'
    status: 'not-required'
  }
]
```

Expected result
Toggle of tabs must work when component is provided with props data to iterate.

Comment: It could be a reason that by passing tabs data as a prop, you are trying to mutate a prop by using it in the `v-model="test.status"`

Comment: For testing purpose, you can copy the prop in local data and try debug it.